# Unwanted half circle when trying to draw quarter circles

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create the Fibonacci spiral with the canvas element in HTML5.

This is my drawing code, this function gets called for every number in the Fibonacci sequence. Side is the square's side length, or the current Fibonacci number. And start is the bottom right corner of each square.

```
function drawSpiral(side, start) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
  ctx.lineTo(start.x, start.y - side);
  ctx.lineTo(start.x - side, start.y - side);
  ctx.lineTo(start.x - side, start.y);
  ctx.lineTo(start.x, start.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  switch (direction) {
    case 0:
      ctx.arc(start.x, start.y - side, side, Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
      break;
    case 1:
      ctx.arc(
        start.x - side,
        start.y - side,
        side,
        1.5 * Math.PI,
        2 * Math.PI,
        true
      );
      break;
    case 2:
      ctx.arc(start.x - side, start.y, side, 2 * Math.PI, Math.PI / 2, true);
      break;
    case 3:
      ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, side, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);
      break;
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

Direction is a number, 0 to 4, that represents the direction of the next square, counterclockwise - 0 = right, 1 = up, ...

It draws the squares and arcs just fine, but it's also drawing half circles everywhere, and I can't figure out why.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni4Yt.png)

Comment: Look like 3/4 circles to me, maybe a problem with clockwise vs counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

The last param is "counterclockwise",

```js
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
```

will do the same as

```js
ctx.arc(x, y, rad, endAngle, startAngle);
// note how start and end have been swapped
```

that is to trace an arc from `endAngle` to `startAngle`, so in your case, it will draw the 3/4 of a circle:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
const startAngle = Math.PI; // 9 o'clock
const endAngle = Math.PI * 1.5; // 12 o'clock

ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, startAngle, endAngle, true);
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(160, 50, 50, endAngle, startAngle);
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you want to trace only the 1/4 of the circle, then don't set this param.

Comment: So this almost works. It's only drawing 1/4th of the circle like it should, but it's not drawing where it should. Instead of inside the square, it goes outside of the square. Or, goes up when it should go down.

Comment: @TreBabcock well you probably have an other issue in your code. You don't show what params are passed to the function, we can't help you more, just remember that both angles are relative to the x-axis, i.e `0` is 3 o'clock.